Firebase Google Sign In provide valid login credentials for your app
I recently uploaded a new app to the Google Play Console to review, then I received an email that said:

Please provide login credentials to the support team before you submit any updated version for another review (select “Test Login Needed” and include the test login account and password details in the open box field).

I am using Firebase Google Sign-in auth in the app. What should I do to avoid this issue also login is important in the app for saving the user data. But how should I fix this issue because it need a Gmail account to log in. How can I provide them dummy credential for this?
